# Transaction remains not confirmed

Tags: transactions, confirmations, bitstamp

On Multibit, one of my transaction to Bitstamp is not confirmed since 5 days (Status icon displays a white square). Apparently the 0.0001 fee was paid. I don’t know where is the money neither what to do.

Comment: Can you give a link to the transaction in blockchain.info?

Comment: Here is the link Multibit provides but it is “not found“ https://blockchain.info/tx-index/4c97251624b26f17544b6d345aba057c3e6838297842c9940d33deb64954ebf4

Comment: Somehow looks like the transaction is not properly broadcasted to the bitcoin network, because it is not visible in blockchain. AFAIK you should see zero confirmations even if there is no transaction fee.

Comment: I see, but then what is supposed to happen to the money?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of things the transaction never made it to the network from your client. Find the "reset blockchain" button in Multibit and wait for it to recover. You won't lose any funds (the ones you "sent" never left) and then you can give it another shot.